# How to specify onchange function that is defined within another function?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have a form with multiple values. When a value is selected/changed, it needs to get passed into a function. This function is however, defined inside another function (and it would be nice to keep it that way). The function in mind also has multiple parameters.

**HTML**

```
<select onChange="selectValue(this.value, x, y)">
<option value="Value 1"> Value 1 </option>
```

**JS**

```
function FunctionOne()
{
  this.selectValue = function(value, x, y) { /* do something */ }
}
```

So I would call this function elsewhere like this:

```
A = new FunctionOne();

A.selectValue(value, 1, 2) // where value is specified from an instance of my data (irrelevant to the problme I'm having)
```

This way the `onchange` function is not found, and ideally I do not want to have it defined outside the other function. Also I am not sure how to handle the multiple inputs that `selectValue` has, in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as `A` exists (assign it onto window or document) where and when the selection changes, you could probably do something like this:

```
<select onChange="function(){A.selectValue(this.value, x, y);}">
```

see [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/d6zdkgLs/)

Comment: Just FYI, the function you specified needs a name;  I added a name but still no luck. When I change the value in the form, `selectValue` is not being called.

Comment: it should not need a name, that would cause it to conflict if the selection changes more than once. this declares the onchange function to be the lambda that does not require any arguments, but in turn calls A.selectValue.

Comment: But then I get `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`

Comment: I'm not sure how to write it to be honest. I have two JS files, one where `functionOne` is defined and one where I call it to use its methods, inside `function load()`. If that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you. However another issue arises: suppose the parameters in my `selectValue` are inputs defined within my JS code, meaning I can't just write a value for them in the HTML code... is there a way around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105793/discussion-between-kris-and-ppg).

Answer (score 0):

A function is a closure, which defines a private scope. I suggest trying the module pattern, which is a great one for all javascript (you'll see it used by jQuery, recommended by Mozilla, etc.). It's like this in your case:

```
function functionOne() {
    var methods =  {
        selectValue: function(value, x, y) {
           //Do something here
        }
    };
    return methods;
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
new functionOne().selectValue(a, b, c);
```